# How to filter multiple values in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, ecmascript-6

I am trying to search an array but in meantime I am able to search on just first name what I want to achieve I want to include last Name too . For example if user search which contain last name or first name I want to display a data . Could someone please help me how to resolve this issue.

**Code**

```
 handleByNameChange = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    let updatedList = this.props.userData.allUsersForFilter;
    updatedList = updatedList.filter(function (item) {
      return item.firstName.toLowerCase().search(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });

    this.setState({
      byNameInputValue: value,
      items: updatedList,
    });
  };
```

**Array of object**

```
[
{firstName: 'Martin', lastName :'Jonas'},
{firstName:'Brad',lastName:'Mickle'},
{fitstName: 'Summer, lastName:'Bride'}
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a function that takes an array to search, and array of property keys to search by, and a value to search for. If array of property keys is empty then no filter should probably occur, return all elements.

- Use array:some to return true/false if using one of the property keys conditions is met.
- Use string::includes to test if a string contains a substring.

searchBy function

```
const searchBy = (arr = [], searchKeys = [], value = '') => {
  return arr.filter(item =>
    searchKeys.length ? searchKeys.some(key =>
      (item[key] || "").toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    ) : true
  );
};
```

Usage

```
handleByNameChange = (e) => {
  const { value } = e.target;
  const updatedList = this.props.userData.allUsersForFilter;

  this.setState({
    byNameInputValue: value,
    items: searchBy(updatedList, ['firstName', 'lastName'], value),
  });
};
```

```js
const data = [
  { firstName: "Martin", lastName: "Jonas" },
  { firstName: "Brad", lastName: "Mickle" },
  { firstName: "Summer", lastName: "Bride" },
  { firstName: "Axel", lastName: "Rod" },
  { firstName: "Mike", lastName: "Haxel" }
];

const searchBy = (arr = [], searchKeys = [], value = '') => {
  return arr.filter(item =>
    searchKeys.length ? searchKeys.some(key =>
      (item[key] || "").toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    ) : true
  );
};

console.log(searchBy(data, [], "Martin"));
console.log(searchBy(data, ["lastName"], ""));
console.log(searchBy(data, ["firstName"], "Martin"));
console.log(searchBy(data, ["firstName"], "Summer"));
console.log(searchBy(data, ["firstName", "lastName"], "ax"));
```

#### Addendum - Searching for combined full name

```
const searchByName = (arr = [], value = "") => {
  return arr.filter(({ firstName = '', lastName = '' }) =>
    [firstName, lastName, `${firstName} ${lastName}`].some(el =>
      el.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    )
  );
};
```

Tries to match first or last name, then full name

```js
const data = [
  { firstName: "Martin", lastName: "Jonas" },
  { firstName: "Brad", lastName: "Mickle" },
  { firstName: "Summer", lastName: "Bride" },
  { firstName: "Axel", lastName: "Rod" },
  { firstName: "Mike", lastName: "Haxel" }
];

const searchByName = (arr = [], value = "") => {
  return arr.filter(({ firstName = '', lastName = '' }) =>
    [firstName, lastName, `${firstName} ${lastName}`].some(el =>
      el.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    )
  );
};

console.log(searchByName(data, "Martin"));
console.log(searchByName(data, ""));
console.log(searchByName(data, "Summer"));
console.log(searchByName(data, "ax"));
console.log(searchByName(data, "Mike Ha"));
```

All code in sandbox demo

[image: Edit filter array multiple values]

Comment: Thank you for answer , when I type something in input for example ( Mike Haxel ) . When I type first name and do space it return nothing . Could you please check

Comment: @Jonas, ah, like you are searching for string literal "Mike Haxel"? For this the above generic per field solution won't quite work, but you'd do a conditional test similar to `\`${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}\`.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())`, where you build a "fullName" string to test. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Jonas Answer updated, included running codesandbox.

Comment: Thanks for an indepth answer @DrewReese

Comment: @DrewReese Getting in error , TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null
  ..   on this line   el.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())

Comment: @Jonas This seems to only be able to occur if one of either `firstName` or `lastName` property doesn't exist in the data array. I updated answer above to provide default values for these destructured properties, though I think this is more a data integrity issue it's a good guard to put in place. Defensive programming.

Answer (score 1):

Use `some` method on combining firstName and lastName array.
(Alternatively return (firstName check || lastName check)

```js
data = [
  { firstName: "Martin", lastName: "Jonas" },
  { firstName: "Brad", lastName: "Mickle" },
  { firstName: "Summer", lastName: "Bride" },
];
value = "ride";
updatedList = data.filter(({ firstName, lastName }) =>
  [firstName, lastName].some(
    (name) => name.toLowerCase().search(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1
  )
);

console.log(updatedList);
```

Comment: I am getting this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null

Comment: @Jonas You had a typo in one of your data array property names, "fitstName" versus "firstName" like the rest. Several of us likely corrected for it but didn't call it out.

Comment: @DrewReese, You are right. Thank you.  I should have mentioned. jonas, This code sample, has the fixed data.

Answer (score 1):

Is this you are looking for ?

```js
const data = [
{firstName: 'Martin', lastName :'Jonas'},
{firstName:'Brad',lastName:'Mickle'},
{firstName:'Summer',lastName:'Bride'}
]

//anyName , which might be first Name or last Name

function filterData(anyName){
        const res = data.filter(name => (name.firstName.includes(anyName)||name.lastName.includes(anyName)))
        return res;
}


console.log(filterData('ride'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
updatedList = updatedList.filter(function (item) {
    if(value) {
        return item.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1 || item.lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      } else {
      return "";
      }
});
```

This is a very basic checking which is clear and concise one, it checks whether the first name or last name values have matched items with provided items or not.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null

Comment: Updated my comment. please check again @Jonas

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
const updatedList = [
  {firstName: 'Martin', lastName :'Jonas'},
  {firstName:'Brad',lastName:'Mickle'},
  {firstName: 'Summer', lastName:'Bride'}
  ];

  updatedList = updatedList.filter(function (item) {
    return item.firstName.toLowerCase().search(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || 
     item.lastName.toLowerCase().search(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
  });
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null

Comment: Check this line here >{>fitstName<: 'Summer, lastName:'Bride'} from your code ... it happened to me also but I fixed in my example...